# Gothic time travel book from the 70’s

Tags: identification-request

My mom read a book where a woman goes to a party at an isolated mansion. She and her date start arguing. She gets out of the car and walks away into the fog, and then she disappears. She turns up into another time. Mom thinks that she had disco/party like clothes on.

Comment: Welcome to Lit.SE! Could you explain what was "gothic" about the book? Every detail can help in IDing a story.

Comment: Also, how long was it, what language was it in, where was it acquired from (geographic location, and store/library/etc.), anything about the cover, etc.?

Comment: It was a paperback and to her knowledge it was about 200/250 pages

Comment: I’m not sure why it was gothic it was just the word my mom used to describe it